# Clear loaded file from object using jquery - HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I am using an embedded windows media player using following code.

```
   <div class="form_date">
    <object classid="clsid:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" width="251" height="62"
        codebase="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/">
        <param name="Filename" value="<%= ViewData["recordSourcePath"] %>" />
        <param name="AutoStart" value="true" />
        <param name="ShowControls" value="true" />
        <param name="BufferingTime" value="2" />
        <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true" />
        <param name="AutoSize" value="false" />
        <param name="InvokeURLs" value="false" />
        <param name="controller" value="true" />
     <%--   !IE--%>
        <object type="video/x-ms-wmv" data="<%= ViewData["recordSourcePath"] %>" width="251"
            height="62">
            <param name="src" value="<%= ViewData["recordSourcePath"] %>" />
            <param name="autostart" value="true" />
            <param name="controller" value="true" />
            <param name="ShowControls" value="true" />
            <param name="BufferingTime" value="2" />
            <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true" />
            <param name="AutoSize" value="false" />
            <param name="InvokeURLs" value="false" />
        </object>
    </object>
</div>

  <input type="submit" value="reload player with empty file" class="button_99" id="stopplay" />
```

Its working fine .Now i have a button in my page.while clicking on that button,I want to clear loaded file from the player using jquery(means, the user cant play file after clicking on that button). Is it possible to clear that without a post back ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.form_date object param[name="Filename"]').remove();
```

Comment: @Null Can you remove the entire `object` ?

Comment: yes i can.   >    $('.form_date object').remove(); its remove the entire object. i dont want to remove the entire object. i just want to stop play ,and user cant play until next post back

Comment: @Null I'm not sure, does it expose any methods like `stop()` ? Can you use HTML5 `video` element?

Comment: @alex..there is a stop method . but thats also not working. and i cant use html 5.:(

Comment: @alex . there was a stop function while accessing object by getelementbyid. i gave an id to the object. its works fine now.Thanx